# how to display preloaded cache images in flutter application

Tags: image, flutter, caching, networking

I am having a sample application which is having networking images, how to display preloaded cache images when navigating between pages. Because it is taking some time for loading from api calls. instead of placeholder how to display same image which loaded previously

Comment: try using ``FutureBuilder``

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package for that

[Check this package](https://pub.dev/packages/cache_image)

You can set the preload image to any image url so when the network image load it will show the image

Answer (score 0):

use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) `cached_network_image`

like this :

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

it will automatically load cached file if its loaded once